# Find all departments which have engineers AND analysts. Use Join and don't forget about the NULL values

Tags: sql, join, null, db2, and-operator

I'm having problem getting the right solution on the asked question. I have 3 tables: employees, departement, salgrade. This is what i got so far:

```
SELECT e0.deptno
FROM EMP AS e0
INNER JOIN dept AS d0 ON e0.deptno=d0.deptno
WHERE
e0.job ='Engineer'
AND
e0.job='Analyst'
AND 
e0.job IS NOT NULL;
```

The expected result is the number of the department, but my result doesn't show anything. I tried using an INTERSECT operator and everything works fine. 
But I don't understand what I'm doing wrong when using JOIN. I think I'm not doing something correctly with the NULL values. Can somebody try to explain me? Thanks

Comment: It looks as if you are repeating the AND on the same column.

    `SELECT e0.deptno
    FROM EMP AS e0
    INNER JOIN dept AS d0 ON e0.deptno=d0.deptno
    WHERE
    e0.job ='Engineer'
    AND
    d0.job='Analyst'
    AND 
    e0.job IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: Because I want to get this two professions from this column and also use the AND operator. Or I'm not understanding what do you mean? @Gnyasha

Comment: I can't use OR or IN, because I'm still not getting the right result. When I use for example IN the result is all departments containing not only this two professions. I need the department who have only the engineers and analysts. @avery_larry

Comment: You could use 2 subqeries -- one for departments with Engineers and one for Analysts -- and then inner join the 2 subqueries together.

Comment: ok I wanted you to try the dept table d0 like `d0.job='Analyst'`

Comment: @avery_larry Yes, i tried that two. But I'm still having the same result. I think the problem is in the AND operator, because it means all the conditions have to be true. And the department number which is the right result, have not only this two professions inside of it, but also others, which are the false condition. But in my assignment I have to use the AND.

Comment: will this work `Select e0.deptno from EMP where( e0.job ='Engineer' or e0.job='Analyst') and e0.job is not null  INNER JOIN dept AS d0 ON e0.deptno=d0.deptno`

Comment: In the dept table I don't have the job column. I only have it in emp table. @Gnyasha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to use a join then:

```
SELECT d0.deptno
FROM dept AS d0 INNER JOIN EMP AS e0 
ON e0.deptno = d0.deptno
WHERE e0.job IN ('Engineer', 'Analyst')
GROUP BY d0.deptno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT e0.job) = 2;
```

But all the info you want is there in the table `EMP`, so you can do it without the join:

```
SELECT deptno
FROM EMP 
WHERE job IN ('Engineer', 'Analyst')
GROUP BY deptno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT job) = 2;
```